# How can I find out if a port on a remote server is open as well as a service is listening on it?

Tags: linux, firewall, port-scanning

I want to check if a set of ports are opened or closed on some remote servers. I went through various discussions on the subject and most of the people suggested to use `nmap`, `nc` and `telnet <server-ip-address> <port-no>`. How can I differentiate these three cases:

- The port is closed on firewall
- The port is open but no service is listening on the port
- The port is open and some service is also listening on it

Comment: If port is open on firewall and no service is listening on it, `telnet` will return "connection timeout". I don't know what makes you cosider this as "not useful"

Comment: If port is open on firewall and no service is listening on it, then `telnet <ip address> <port-no>` would return "connection refused".
Yes, after reading the answer below and your comment, I tried it again and it's giving the results as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well if you use telnet command to check the port connectivity, it will show

- "connection timeout" if the port is blocked by the firewall
- "Connection refused" if the service is down/not listening on specified port, but port is reachable.
- "connected to server_ip" if connection is successful

Answer (score 8):

### Useful utilities :

- 1.Telnet
- 2.nc
- 3.nmap

> Scenario: For checking remote system tcp 80 port status

### Usage :

```
telnet myserver.com 80 
nc -v myserver.com 80
nmap myserver.com 80
```

### Response Analysis :

if you get a time out or deny  : the port is not open

suppose if you get "Connection refused" : then port is open but process is not listerning

If you get a connection successful : Port is open and process is listen

### Solution:

start/restart the listening process (if connection refused)

Ask network team to monitor the connection we can confirm whether it is blocked from intermediate network firewall or from server firewall/iptables

Note :

- Suppose firewall configured to Reject packets instead of Drop then u
  will get "connection refused" error , so here in this case we can't
  ensure wheteher process is listern or not.

For checking udp port (like ntp) you can use below nc option

> nc -uzv yourserver.com 123

Answer (score 3):

Although *telnet* or *netcat* can be used to determine port reachability, **nmap** is the standard port scanning tool.

The nmap default option (TCP SYN scan) determines if a given port is filtered or not by a firewall.

```
nmap -sS <host> -p <port>
```

If you want a reliable differentiation between the open, closed, and filtered states, use the -sY option (SCTP INIT scan)

```
nmap -sY <host> -p <port>
```